# Configuring dynamic e-mail aliases such as "user+keyword"

Tags: ubuntu, email, exim, courier, aliases

My Ubuntu server is using Exim4/Courier for emails and I'd like to know if it's possible to create dynamic email aliases for receiving emails like this:

client+client1name@domain.com
client+client2name@domain.com
client+client3name@domain.com
client+younameit@domain.com

One single account, infinite aliases that you don't need to create explicitly.

That's different from a catch-all address because, well, it caches everything (including spam). With such aliases, you receive emails sent to client@domain.com and client+anything@domain.com only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set

```
local_part_suffix = +* : -*
local_part_suffix_optional
```

in your `exim.conf`

- [Doc link](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html#SECID55)
- [unix.se question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115008/email-server-with-automatic-sign-aliases)

Comment: Thanks for the information. You seem to be completely right. Unfortunately, I was not able to make it work yet. I'm on Ubuntu and it looks like I have to work with `exim4.conf.template` and `update-exim4.conf.conf`, but my changes are not applied with the command `update-exim4.conf`. I guess I'll have to investigate a bit more.